# Very low FPS on a Rpi 4B (2.7G RAM dedicated for GPU) with wand (ImageMagick) video processing

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video, wand

So I am getting VERY low FPS on the raspberry pi 4B when I modify live footage from a webcam to a 'barrel' effect using wand image processing. How can I fix this issue, if possible within the restraints of the hardware? I have a 4GB RAM Rpi 4B. If this is impossible to fix with my current modules without removing the barrel effect, do you have any recommendations for alternate libraries which could achieve the same effect? I need live footage displayed at this pixel dimension for a VR/FPV project I am working on.

Here is my code:

```
import wand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wand.image import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vid.set(3,640) #Defines width - id:3 for width; to 640 pixels
vid.set(4,480) #Defines height - id:4; 480 pixels
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
org = (120,100)
fontScale = 1
color = (255, 0, 0)
thickness = 2
while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    cv2.imwrite('cur_img.jpeg', frame)
    with Image(filename='cur_img.jpeg') as img:
        img.virtual_pixel = 'transparent'
        img.distort('barrel', (0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
        img_opencv = np.array(img)
    img1 = img_opencv
    # Read Second Image
    img2 = img_opencv
    frame = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)  
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You might get better times with OpenCV processing using cv2.remap(). I do not have a barrel distortion handy, but do have a spherical distortion example. Both are radial distortions with different equations. You might search google for the barrel example. It might have been done already

Comment: With respect to Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick, you might check your Imagemagick resources to see what limitations you have or set your policy.xml file to relax any limitations.

Comment: I do not believe that Imagemagick barrel distortion is GPU accelerated according to the list of GPU methods at https://imagemagick.org/script/opencl.php

Comment: Thanks to @fmw42, your advice on the remap led me to a script that I modified to work perfectly for barrel distortion on pure OpenCV. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Curious! What script did you modify?  Can you post the link? Also would be nice if you post your solution.

Comment: No problem! Ill post the link in the morning.